# Использование try/catch в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Видел много статей, которые негативно отзываются об использовании try/catch в T-SQL и чуть ли не относят это к антипаттернам.

Справедливо ли это?

Comment: А другие способы отлова ошибок в tsql есть ? вообще что то мне подсказывает что ваш вопрос напрашивается на закрытие по "основано на мнениях, а не фактах"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я не встречал ни одной статьи с такими отзывами, сейчас специально поискал - нашел одно обсуждение - автор рассказывает об одном ДБА, высказывающим свое негативное отношение к данной конструкции - большинство комментариев в обсуждении сводятся к тому, что нужно держать такого ДБА подальше от баз данных.

Понятно, что как любая конструкция, она должна быть правильно понимаема и используема - с помощью этого блока можно случайно потерять информацию о важных ошибках, которые должны были бы привести к падению программы.

Блок TRY/CATCH весьма полезен в случаях использования транзакций, когда вам нужно обеспечить целостность - в начале блока TRY вы начинаете транзакцию, в конце - заканчиваете, а в блоке CATCH транзакцию откатываете (если мы попали в этот блок, значит что-то в транзакции пошло не так) и возвращаете ошибку выполнения процедуры.

Обычно такой блок многие зашивают в шаблон процедуры, чтобы не писать подобные обработчики каждый раз. Пример такого шаблона:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE <put procedure name and parameters here>
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    -- Put your code here
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
    DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

    PRINT 'Actual error number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));
    PRINT 'Actual line number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
  END CATCH
END;
GO
```